# Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение (python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

у меня есть телеграмм бот, работающий асинхронно, но часто вылетают ошибки в консоль, как я понимаю, связанные с подключением. Иногда бот может упасть, иногда продолжить работать (не факт, что он падает из-за этих ошибок)
Ошибки:

```
INFO:aiogram:Bot: BotEx [@BotEx]
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Start polling.
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
```

Код запуска бота с подключением к бд:

```
import logging 
import asyncio 
import sys 
import aiomysql 
import db  
from aiomysql import create_pool 
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
 from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor  
import keyboards  
from messages import MESSAGES  
from settings import mysql  
from config import USER, PASSWORD, HOST, PORT, DATABASE, TOKEN, PAYMENTS_PROVIDER_TOKEN  

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  
client = Bot(token=TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')
 dp = Dispatcher(client, storage=MemoryStorage(), loop=loop)  
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

   async def db_config():     
      if not mysql.conn:         
           try:             
               mysql.conn = await create_pool(                 
               host=HOST,                 
               port=PORT,                 
               user=USER,                 
               password=PASSWORD,                 
               db=DATABASE,                 
               charset='utf8',                 
               use_unicode=True,                 
               loop=loop             
               )          
           except aiomysql.Error as e:             
               print(f'Error connecting: {e}')             
               sys.exit(1)   

if __name__ == '__main__':     
      loop.run_until_complete(db_config())      

      from handlers import dp     
      executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще вариант ошибок тут не один

Если бот может продолжать работу после этой ошибки, вероятно, проблема не в коде бота, а в сетевых условиях. Можно добавить обработку исключений в код, чтобы бот мог перезапустить подключение в случае потери связи с тг

Такого рода

```
async def db_config():
    if not mysql.conn:
        connected = False
        while not connected:
            try:
                mysql.conn = await create_pool(
                    host=HOST,
                    port=PORT,
                    user=USER,
                    password=PASSWORD,
                    db=DATABASE,
                    charset='utf8',
                    use_unicode=True,
                    loop=loop
                )
                connected = True
            except aiomysql.Error as e:
                if isinstance(e, ConnectionResetError):
                    logging.warning('ConnectionResetError occurred, retrying in 5 seconds...')
                    await asyncio.sleep(5)
                else:
                    logging.error(f'Error connecting: {e}')
                    sys.exit(1)
```

Если будет ошибка ConnectionResetError, то сообщение пойдет в лог и будет 5 сек ждать прежде чем повторить соединение

Comment: Есть вероятность, что проблема с сервером, где-то на просторах находил, что мол нужно установить лупу вроде policity какой-то, точно не помню, но я не смог его интегрировать в свое подключение. Кстати у меня в боте есть асинхронные слипы, работающие по типу таймеров или будильников, они сбросятся при переподключении к бд (как я понял разрывается соединение с бд)?

Comment: да сбросятся, но можно добавь функцию которая будет это все сохранять в бд, например и обновлять постоянно

Comment: Сделал такую штуку, которая берет даты из бд и пихает их в слипы в случае перезапуска бота, но все же при отключении вероятнее всего будут и сбрасываться состояния (к примеру прохождение регистрации), но спасибо за код переподключения)